# AJAX won't get JSON data second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm sending Ajax request to a php file, that file returns an JSON array of the submitted data, the first time is great, it sends the data and gets it, so i can use it, but second time it gives me an error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

My goal is to validate the data in the php file, if the data is not validated then i'm adding an error classes to the fields that are not validated, then the user correct those fields, and sends the form again, without refreshing.

My testing shows that its working for the first time, but when i want to send the form the second time, it gives me the above error, any clues what it can be?

AJAX :

```
$('#ajax').submit('submit', function(){

var that = $(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
    var that = $(this),
    name = that.attr('name'),
    value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    cache:false,

    success: function(response){
        var json = response,
        obj = JSON.parse(json);
        if(obj.title == 'Mrs.'){
        //  $('#title').addClass('has-warning');
            $(function () {
              $('#name').tooltip({ 'title': 'Please fill name'});
            });
        }
        alert(obj.title);
    }

});
return false;
});
```

PHP file:

```
if(Input::exists()){
if(token::check(Input::get('token'))){

    echo json_encode(
    array(
        "title" => Input::get('title')
        )
    );
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sending the exact same params each time? Look at Chrome Dev Tools at the response and you'll see if the responses are identical or not. My bet is that the conditional fails on the second time and so the response is empty. Try removing the conditional and see if you still get the same result.

Comment: Error means second time the format of your JSON is wrong. you must check your second time's response

Comment: The error message suggests that `obj = JSON.parse(json);` javascript line in your success callback is failing because `json` is not valid json. I would take a look at what is coming  back at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token check is the culprit here. It's not working the second time because it's returning an empty response. This is because you probably need to recreate a new Token and send it with the first response. To test if this is the issue, just write :

```
if(Input::exists()){
 if(token::check(Input::get('token'))){

  echo json_encode(
  array(
    "title" => Input::get('title')
    )
  );
 }else{
   echo json_encode(
     array("title" => 'See? You need to update token')
   );
 }
}
```

You should regenerate a new Token and then update it's value in the form :

```
echo json_encode(
     array("newToken" => Token::generate() )
   );
```

Comment: lol, js is the only language i feel stupid when i'm using it, i'm new to js, because of that i got stupid errors, as i think the problem in js and its my fualt because i don't know the language, and then i'm finding out that i have stupid errors like the above.

Comment: It's not stupid. I had the same error and spent a day trying to understand what was causing it ;) Then I discovered frameworks and these kinds of error became a thing from the past